# Viewing bootstrap pane when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able view my pane when I click on the link "Forgot your password?".

Right now what I have done is that I've created a tab for the specific pane. When I click on the tab or the link, I am able to view the pane. I created a JS function that will "click" the tab and display the pane when I click the "Forgot your password?" link.

I do not want the tab to be displayed. So I want to view the pane only when clicking the "Forgot your password?" link. I think I can achieve this by hiding the tab but the logic still exists. I believe I can also achieve this without using the tab, however I am not sure how to do this.

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/essnm8bd/1/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var join_btn = document.getElementById("join-btn"),
        signin_btn = document.getElementById("signin-btn"),
        reset_password_link = document.getElementsByClassName("reset-password-link")[0];

    join_btn.addEventListener("click", joinSelected);
    signin_btn.addEventListener("click", signInSelected);
    reset_password_link.addEventListener("click", resetPasswordSelected);

    function joinSelected() {
        $('[href="#signup-pane"]').trigger('click');
    }
    function signInSelected() {
        $('[href="#signin-pane"]').trigger('click');
    }
    function resetPasswordSelected() {
        $('[href="#reset-password-pane"]').trigger('click');
    }


});
```

HTML:

```
  <nav class="navbar nav-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="navbar-left">
        <li><a>LOGO</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="logged-out-nav nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a id="join-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn">Join Spark</a></li>
        <li><a id="signin-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn">Sign in</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- tabs -->
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" id="signin-tab"><a href="#signin-pane" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Sign in</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" id="new-account-tab"><a href="#signup-pane" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">New Account</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" id="reset-password-tab"><a href="#reset-password-pane" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">test</a></li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Tab panes -->
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="signup-pane">
              <form class="signup-form" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input id="signup-firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
                <input id="signup-lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                <input id="signup-email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                <input id="signup-password" placeholder="Password">
                <input id="signup-confirm-password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
              </form>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="signin-pane">
              <form class="signin-form" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input id="signin-email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                <input id="signin-password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
              </form>
              <p>
                <a href="#reset-password-pane" class="reset-password-link">
                  Forgot your password?
                </a>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="reset-password-pane">
              <input id="forgot-email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show/hide the tab using bootstrap [`X.bs.tab` events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events):

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $("#reset-password-pane, #reset-password-tab").show();
}).not('#reset-password-tab a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $("#reset-password-pane, #reset-password-tab").hide();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xznaL30s/)

---

Or you can wrap your form into a div, make another form inside another div and toggle these divs on click:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="signin-pane">
    <div class="login-tab-container">
        <form>
            ... login fields ...
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="login-tab-container" style="display:none;">
        <form>
            ... reset password field ...
        </form>
    </div>
    <p>
        <a href="#" class="reset-password-link">Forgot your password?</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(".reset-password-link").click( function() {
    $('.login-tab-container').slideToggle(200);
    $.trim($(this).text()) === 'Close' ? $(this).text('Forgot your password?') : $(this).text('Close')
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9t29ojx2/)